Antenna Selection and Placement for high altitude rocket ground link
As a part of my rocketry club this year, I am building our rf ground link system. I have the radio selection and design mostly finished, with the final hurdle being that of antenna choice and mounting location.
System Details
434Mhz radio transceiver with +30.2dbm (1W) of output power. with a maximum required distance of ~10 miles
The rocket airframe will be entirely carbon fiber except for the nose cone. With internals containing multiple thick metal bulkheads
Nose cone will always be pointing up (away from the ground station)
The ground station will be on the ground near the launchpad (so roughly always directly beneath the rocket). While I would not be opposed to moving the ground station more away from the pad to achieve a better angle, I would perfer to stay near the pad as thats where the infrastructure exists
Potential Options
I do not have a lot of experience with antenna design/emission patterns so my concern is that our signal will experience a lot of interference / deflection from the carbon fiber body.
The first antenna design I thought of would just be a standard 1/4 wave monopole antenna facing upwards in the nose cone, however, it seems that the radiation would be spread mostly outward instead of downward and would be largely blocked by the airframes
The second antenna design would be a strip of copper tape (or something similar) mounted to the exterior of the rocket (running down the length of the rocket). In my mind this seems better as it would potentially interfere less with the airframes, but it still seems to me that the radiation would be mostly pointed outwards.
There's some debate on the team about which of these two options would be better, and I am wondering if a better design exists. Of course, we are limited by aerodynamics and space, so anything outside of the rocket has to be relatively flat and secure, anything inside has to fit within the nosecone.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks,
Ethan
Edits
Additional Rocket Details
Rocket length: 124s inch
Rocket diameter: 6inch
Nosecone length: 42inch
Fin size: 
The rocket is a solid propellant rocket
Additional Radio details
our radio is a custom-made PCB utilizing a CC1200 transceiver chip as well as a FEM to boost the power. (If anyone wants to take a look at this info I can send schematics)
we will be manufacturing 2 of these identical boards and using one as a receiver on the ground station and one as a transmitter on the rocket
The plan is to have the capability to do both an uplink and a downlink but the system will most likely just be a downlink
Our ground station will be using a 70cm YAGI antenna (not yet chosen), with a highly sophisticated tracking system (someone's hand).
I have not made a link margin, and honestly, I have never heard of it. Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems to be a way to estimate the received power and plan antenna gains accordingly. My plan for this was to just field test the system across a lake or something similar.

What's the diameter and length of the rocket, length of nosecone? Does it have fins at the back, how big? What is the link margin of the chosen TxRx pair at 10 miles, assuming omni antennas? Will you use a CP Yagi on the ground?

I added some extra information to the post, please let me know if I missed anything

Good info. For antennas, the back edge of the fin looks very appealing. Is it possible to extend it slightly with a piece of thin fibreglass printed circuit board? Or switch to using fibreglass for the back 2" of the fin, and then make the antenna out of copper tape on the surface?

For a link budget: to avoid disappointment at peak altitude, you should calculate, and then measure, how much "spare" signal will be available at that range. Considering the antennas may not be perfectly aligned, I would say you need at least 10 dB, preferably 20 dB of margin. i.e. the radio should almost-work under ideal conditions, with 20 dB less gain, or at 10 x longer range, than your actual mission requires.  This should not be difficult to achieve.

Path loss for 70 cm at 15 km is -109 dB. CC1200 says receive sensitivity is -109 dBm at 50 kbps, so it would almost work with 0 dBm transmit power. With +14 dBm and a modest yagi it is quite likely to work. +30 dBm is plenty, might even be a waste of power and weight. Now you should do some tests to be sure. The receiver on the ground could be affected by other strong signals (though anywhere you can fly a rocket to 10+ km is probably fairly quiet).

Ill have to check on fin mounting, anything outside of the nosecone, will be less than ideal for the structures folks. But I have seen a lot of people recommend mounting antennas on the fins, which makes sense since it would provide the clearest path

My brother used to do this sort of thing, although many years ago.  His transmitter was in the mW range and used 1/4 wave whips in a cross pattern.  The ground station used an array of four 13 element yagis.  While he was only sending MCW,over FM the big challenge was knowing where to point the Yagis and keep them pointed at the rapidly descending payload.  So whatever tracking antenna you use, it will need to be able to move quickly.  (We used the "Armstrong" method...me turning the array by hand.)

@tomnexus +30dBm is probably not so much a waste of power because the antenna is most likely very suboptimally placed on or near carbon fiber tube. I don't think the antenna is going be anything like 0dBD. My cubesat friends are using antennas like -10dBD or worse.

Oh amateur radio and rocketry, very nice combo!
So, first observation: you will want your antenna to be at the outside of your payload, probably inside the fairing, but not hidden between your metal apparatus.
How possible that is depends on size compared to wavelength. We know the wavelength (from your frequency), but we don't know the diameter of your rocket, and the height along which we could affix antennas. Probably, assuming you can use parts of the motor / fuel tanks as surface to carry antennas (I assume this isn't a multi-stage rocket that discards the last stage and only orbits your nosecone?).
Second observation: You don't seem to have a link budget yet.
But that would be necessary to decide on the antenna, because it would tell you how much gain the system would need to have in the direction of your ground station.
If you need help setting up a link budget, that would make for a good question for here! Put all info you have on the system into the question :)
And knowing how much gain you need would define how you'd design your antenna, and whether you're going for a single antenna (like in your proposed rotationally invariant solution), or multiple (for example, four patch antenna arrays on the outer surface, one looking in every cardinal direction, such that you always have one "pointing somewhat" towards you). How realistic that is depends on rocket geometry and material, and also a bit on flame properties. (If you expect the burn to cause a large flare: fire is actually plasma / ionized gases, so that it is closer to a rusty piece of metal than to plain air from the view of an antenna designer. If it's a narrow torch your motor design causes: it's out of your way, anyways).
Regarding ground station placement: well, launch is a critical time and you would want to have as much data as possible – probably because either doing measurements and linking them down during the launch is the whole point, and hence the launch would be a bit wasted if you didn't, or because you getting the payload to high altitude is the whole point and you really want to understand the telemetry you're getting from your launch vehicle in case something doesn't go perfectly nominal.
So, taking extra effort to make sure you have optimal reception conditions sounds more than reasonable. If you'd asked me, I'd probably have two or three ground stations, all pointing their antennas at the expected trajectory, but not being too narrow in their pointing (because otherwise you need to start implementing rocket tracking and uh… no). I don't know the characteristics of your 434 MHz link, but my guess at this point is that

it's one way, downlink only (please confirm)
it's a commercial, tested transmitter of well-understood waveform
your receiver is some SDR device which does software decoding and either is a software implementation on your laptop or is able to send the data via some digital link practically anywhere.

I'd say from these points arises the question of why not place two ground stations at good vantage points, and "concentrate" the received data on the laptop you have at the launch site. Specifics of that system design would again depend on your geometry and link budget, as well as the planned trajectory, velocity and travel duration.

Hi, thanks for your response, I added more information to the original post, but just to reiterate:

it will most likely be a one way downlink, but the radios can be used as two way and I would like to leave that option open
it uses commercial IC's to handle all radio aspects but the full radio is a custom made PCB including other control options
the reciever will be one of the PCB's configured into receive mode

I have never made a link budget before and would appreciate any help you would be willing to give on making one.

Depending on your link budget calculation, your antenna may not have to be very high performance but you probably want to factor in mechanical strength and robust operation.
If you were to place a copper tape strip outside the carbon fiber tube, I would make it a loop shaped around the circumference, or a short helix and design a custom matching network for it. Lifting the copper tape off the carbon fiber tube, even by a few millimeters, may improve the performance.
If you can place the antenna inside the tube but near the bottom of the rocket (facing and firing back to the ground), a patch antenna might be a good option. It is mechanically simple and has a beam pattern suitable for your application as long as it points down to the ground.
